# How can I edit FixtureDef propterties on a body at runtime?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I have been working on this problem for awhile and I have not found any plausible solution for this problem. All I have been trying to do is edit the collision filtering properties on a box2D body. I understand that I have to destroy the fixture and then create a new one, but when I go to create a new Fixture thats when my program throws a null pointer.

```
private FixtureDef fdef;
public void updateContactSensor(short mask)
{
    fdef = new FixtureDef();
    fdef.filter.categoryBits=Constants.PLAYER_CAT;
    fdef.filter.maskBits=mask;
    PolygonShape shape=new PolygonShape();
    shape.setAsBox(10, 10);
    Fixture f=MainRunner.getDemo().getPlayer().getFixture();
    MainRunner.getDemo().getPlayer().getBody().destroyFixture(f);
    MainRunner.getDemo().getPlayer().getBody().createFixture(
             MainRunner.getDemo().getPlayer().getFixtureDef());
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082030/can-i-change-filter-all-the-time-in-box2d

Answer (score 0):

try this:

in your code at line

```
MainRunner.getDemo().getPlayer().getBody().createFixture(
             MainRunner.getDemo().getPlayer().getFixtureDef());
```

add this change:

```
//..
MainRunner.getDemo().getPlayer().getBody().createFixture(
             fdef);
.//
```

P.S: if it works not notified that I delete the answer. You could put the stacktrace?